# Grid sin scroll bar horizontal

Tags: scroll, genexus, grid, scrollbar

¿Cómo puedo habilitar el scroll bar horizontal en un grid en genexus 16 u9?
Por default se habilita el scroll bar vertical, pero no así con el scroll horizontal.

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como estas?

Si tu pregunta esta relacionada a Android/iOS, lo que deberias hacer es utilizar, parado en el grid, la propiedad: Control Type = "Horizontal Grid", o tambien utilizando Control Type = "Grid" y ademas setear la propiedad Scroll Direction = "Horizontal".

Si tu pregunta es orientada a web, te paso informacion aqui:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30594,HowTo%3A%20Using%20Horizontal%20Grid%20control%20in%20Web%20applications

Saludos, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias, espero que tu también. Gracias nuevamente por apoyarme. Mi busqueda es para el caso web, revise el link que me compartes, pero esa info es mas bien para hacer el efecto carrusel, y tenga ese efecto "horizontal". Mi problema es más bien para un grid de datos. Saludos